# If $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ is a homeomorphism, then $\lim_{\| x \| \to \infty} \| f(x) \| = +\infty$

Tags: general-topology, limits, normed-spaces

> If $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ is a homeomorphism, then $\lim_{\| x \| \to \infty} \| f(x) \| = +\infty$.

**My attempt:**

I need to show that $\forall M\in\mathbb{R}: \exists R>0: \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^d:\| x\| \ge R \Rightarrow \| f(x)\| \ge M$. Suppose that this is not the case, i.e. $\exists M: \forall R: \exists x\in\mathbb{R}^d: \| x\| \ge R \quad\& \quad \| f(x)\|< M.$ Pick such an $M\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: \exists x_n: \|x_n\|\ge n \quad \&\quad \| f(x_n)\|<M.$$ Then we have that $x_n\not\to 0$. I thought of using the bijectivity of $f$, i.e. $\exists y_n\in\mathbb{R}^d: f(x_n)=y_n \iff x_n = f^{-1}(y_n)$. Then we would have that $\| f^{-1}(y_n)\|\ge n \quad \& \quad \| y_n\| < M$.

I want to show that $f^{-1}(x_n)\not\to f^{-1}(0)$ as this would imply that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous in $0$, a contradiction. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: "I want to show that $f^{-1}(x_n)\not\to f^{-1}(0)$ as this would imply that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous in $0$": You mean $y_n$, but I still don't understand why this should be true.

Comment: I'm not sure I see where your contradiction is; $x_n$ does not tend towards $0$, and that isn't incompatible with $f^{-1}(x_n)$ not tending towards $f^{-1}(0)$ (in fact, they are equivalent since $f$ is a homeomorphism). One idea you might consider is using sequential compactness to see that a subsequence of $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}} = (y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges, and show that no subsequence of $(f^{-1}(f(x_n)))_{n\in\mathbb{N}} = (f^{-1}(y_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ can converge, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from here:

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}. \exists x_n: \|x_n\|\ge n \quad \&\quad \| f(x_n)\|<M$

I would use the fact that every sequence which lies in a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^d$ has a convergent subsequence. Notice this applies to the sequence $f(x_n)$, which lies in the compact set $\{x: ||x|| \leq M\}$. Let $(f(x_{n_m}))_{m=1}^\infty$ be such a subsequence, with $f(x_{n_m}) \to L$ as $m \to \infty$.

By continuity of $f^{-1}$, we must have $f^{-1}(f(x_{n_m})) = x_{n_m} \to f^{-1}(L)$ as $m \to \infty$. But this is a contradiction, since $||x_{n_m}|| \to \infty$.

Comment: In other words, if the proposition were false then $f$ maps some unbounded set $S$ to  a bounded set $T$, but then $f^{-1}$ continuously maps the compact set $\overline T$ to an unbounded,& hence non-compact set, which is impossible.